# How to glue some isomorphic graphs to a common vertex or a vertex set

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have some isomorphic graphs (in fact, non-isomorphic graphs are also possible), and I want to glue them to a vertex. (Note that here this vertex is a cut vertex).
Strictly speaking, two graphs $G_1$ with distinguished vertex $v_1$ and $G_2$ with distinguished vertex $v_2$, is formed by identifying vertices( gluing vertices) $v_1$ and $v_2$ that is, the vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ are replaced by a single vertex $v$ adjacent to the same vertices in $G_1$ as $v_1$ and the same vertices in $G_2$ as $v_2$. If it is not necessary $v_1$ or $v_2$ may not be specified.

For example, as shown in the figure below, four $K_4$ are glued together on a vertex $u$. I am not sure if there is a function in mathematica that can do this quickly.

[image]

Sagemath seems to be relatively easy with built-in function merge_vertices.

```
g=graphs.CompleteGraph(4)
I = g.disjoint_union(g)
I = I.disjoint_union(g)
I.relabel()
I.plot()
I.merge_vertices([1,7,8])
I.relabel()
I.plot()
```

[image]

Of course, this problem can be extended, that is, two graphs can be glued together on a subgraph.
[image]

*GraphDisjointUnion* can get the disjoint union of several isomorphic graphs, but it is far from my requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it with my IGraph/M package:

We start with $K_4$:

```
g = CompleteGraph[4];
```

Make 5 copies and create the disjoint union:

```
bg = IGDisjointUnion[ConstantArray[g, 5]]
```

Unlike `GraphDisjointUnion`, `IGDisjointUnion` preserves the correspondence between the vertices of the original graphs and the new graph. The vertices will be named as `{graphIndex, originalName}`, where `graphIndex` is the index of the graph in the input list and `originalName` is the original vertex name.

Let us contract vertices which had the name `1` in the original $K_4$:

```
IGVertexContract[
 bg,
 {Cases[VertexList[bg], {_, 1}]}
]
```

[image]

Glue them together on the `1-2` subgraph, i.e. contract both 1s and 2s:

```
IGVertexContract[
 bg,
 {Cases[VertexList[bg], {_, 1}], Cases[VertexList[bg], {_, 2}]}
 ]
```

[image]

Here you may also use the built-in `VertexContract` instead of `IGVertexContract`. The advantage of `IGVertexContract` is that: (1) It provides an unambiguous way to specify vertices even when vertex names are lists (2) It can simultaneously contract multiple sets of vertices. `VertexContract` did not do this before version 12.1, despite what the documentation seemed to suggest.

Comment: If we have two graphs that are not isomorphic, the function IGVertexContract  fails.

Comment: @licheng I can't comment on that without a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking of creating a new question.